# I am creating a simple JDBC Java Application, Getting Class not found exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am creating a simple JDBC Java Application, and I added mysql jar file in Library and it is saving in Reference Libraries, but I am getting error as, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

I am using mysql 8.0.12

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at Jdbc.main(Jdbc.java:15)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Jdbc.main(Jdbc.java:32)
```

my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Savepoint;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Jdbc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con=null;
        Statement st=null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/rakeshdb","root","raki");
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        st=con.createStatement();


        st.executeUpdate("insert into emp values(111,'RAkE',100000,'hyd')");
        Savepoint sp=con.setSavepoint();
        st.executeUpdate("insert into emp values(222,'RAkESH',10000,'sec')");
        con.rollback();
        st.executeUpdate("insert into emp values(333,'RAkI',1000,'bvrm')");
        con.commit();
        System.out.println("Transcation SUCCESS");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            con.rollback();
            System.out.println("Transcation FAILURE");
        } catch (Exception e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
        }

    }finally {

    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is expected :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
```

as  `com.mysql.jdbc.driver` is not the JDBC driver class for MySQL.
But `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install SQL driver for Java from their(SQL) site and input .jar file inside Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you have provided wrong driver class details in `Class.forName()`.

What I would recommend to you is to not use this at all as  `Class.forName()` is not needed since JDBC 4.0. Any JDBC 4.0 drivers that are found in your classpath are automatically loaded.

So, try `commenting that line` and run your program. If you have the driver jar file in the class-path, it should get automatically loaded(Assuming you are using JDBC 4.0 driver)